# how to disable button on change using jquery

Tags: jquery, forms

I want to disable button on change file and want to make check whether the file is in appropriate resolution or not if yes submit button enable if not then disable any suggestion please I want to use jQuery.

Comment: please add some code or your effort so we can help you we can't provide help when you have done nothing try to work and if then you fails ask here but at least try yourself first

Comment: thanks for your reply jagdish  but I just assuming it haven't try it yet but I will try and make sure this will not happen again please consider about vote please

Comment: its ok try the code and post here and i will definitely help u out

Comment: Yes may be tell us what you are thinking to do. A code is always appreciated. Whenever you try and get an Error, post it here and we will help.

Comment: its ok abhishek put some code we will help you i vote up so you can carry on here you are new so please read the instruction before putting question

Comment: You've read (or last paged down...) the [tour] so you should know what sort of questions to [ask].  You're getting downvotes as you're expected to have at least had a go - show the code you've tried so far and explain the problems you're having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this as am assuming a image and am checking the resolutions and then i disable or enable the button as per requirements and also am clearing selected
image so user can't upload the wrong format .

```
<script>




    var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

                                    $("#file").change(function (e) {
                                        var file, img;


                                        if ((file = this.files[0])) {
                                            img = new Image();
                                            img.onload = function () {
                                                //alert(this.width + " " + this.height);
                                                var widthofimage = this.width;
                                                var heightofimage = this.height;

                                                if (widthofimage < 1920 && heightofimage < 850 || widthofimage != 1920 && heightofimage != 850 || widthofimage > 1920 && heightofimage > 850) {
                                                    swal({
                                                        title: "Please review",
                                                        text: "Please Upload Image of 1920 X 850",
                                                        icon: "error",
                                                    });

                                                    document.getElementById("file").value = "";
                                                } else {

                                                    $('input[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');

                                                }

                                            };
                                            img.onerror = function () {
                                                alert("not a valid file: " + file.type);
                                            };
                                            img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);


                                        }

                                    });






</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable html input elements by the following ways:

**1 :- $(this).attr("disabled", true);**

**2 :- $(this).prop('disabled', true);**

Try The following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#fileUpload").change(function(){
        //$(this).attr("disabled", true);
        $('#btnTest').prop('disabled', true);
        });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input ID="fileUpload"  runat="server" type="file">
<button type="button" id="btnTest">CLICK ME</button>

</body>
</html>
```

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#fileUpload").change(function(){
            //$(this).attr("disabled", true);
            $('#btnTest').prop('disabled', true);
            });
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
    </head>
    <body>
    <input ID="fileUpload"  runat="server" type="file">
    <button type="button" id="btnTest">CLICK ME</button>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: @Abhishek Saini try this

Comment: thanks for reply issue is resolved thanks for your help @faraz